# two views sharing one viewmodel listbox doesn't update

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

I have two windows (views) and they share the same viewmodel. I use one window to input data and the second to order it in 3 different listboxes (observablecollections) based on the value of one combobox in the input window. The problem I have is that the input doesn't show up in the listboxes. it's like the observable collection doesn't update.

This is the code I have in the input window

```
public partial class AddPerson : Window
{
    public NetworkViewModel MyViewModel;
    public AddPerson()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new NetworkViewModel();
    }
}
```

and in xaml

```
<TextBox x:Name="tb_firstName"  Text="{Binding Path=FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="cb_group"  ItemsSource="{Binding GroupLevel}"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGroupLevel}"/>
```

in the displaywindow with the 3 listboxes I have

```
public partial class Display : Window
{
    public NetworkViewModel MyViewModel;
    public AddPerson()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new NetworkViewModel();
    }
}
```

and this is the xaml for the display window

```
<ListBox x:Name="lb1"  GotFocus="textBox1_visible" ItemsSource="{Binding NetworkList1}" dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True"
     dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True" SelectedItem ="{Binding Path=SelectedItemGroup, Mode=TwoWay}" />

<ListBox x:Name="lb2"  GotFocus="textBox1_visible" ItemsSource="{Binding NetworkList2}" dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True"
     dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True" SelectedItem ="{Binding Path=SelectedItemGroup, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

This is what my viewmodel looks like

```
public class NetworkViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private ObservableCollection<Person> _networkList1 = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    public ObservableCollection<Person> NetworkList1 //Binds with the listbox
    {
        get { return _networkList1; }
        set { _networkList1 = value; } 
    }

 private string _firstName;
 public string FirstName  
    {
        get { return this._firstName; }
        set { this._firstName = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("FirstName"); }
    }
 private string _group;
 public string Group  
    {
        get { return _group; }
        set { _group = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Group"); }
    }

 public NetworkViewModel() 
    {
        AddPersonCommand = new RelayCommand(AddPerson);
    }

 private ICommand _addPersonCommand;
 public ICommand AddPersonCommand
    {
        get { return _addPersonCommand; }
        set { _addPersonCommand = value; }
    }

 public void AddPerson(object obj)
    {
        if (SelectedGroupLevel == "Primary")
        {

             NetworkList1.Add(new Person()
            {
                FirstName = this.FirstName,
                Group = this.Group,
            });
             MessageBox.Show("Person successfully added");
        }
        else if (SelectedGroupLevel == "Secondary")
        {
             NetworkList2.Add(new Person()
            {
                FirstName = this.FirstName,
                Group = this.Group,
            });
             MessageBox.Show("Person successfully added");
        }
     }
```

When I click the add button in the input window I can see the message in the messagebox, which means that the data is added to the observable collection, but I don't see it displayed, Hopefully somebody can help me with this issue. I'm very green to wpf and mvvm. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Problem lies in the way you are using view models. You are creating two separate instances of your view model one in the AddPerson view and one in the Display view. When you add an item in the AddPerson view it is updating its own view model not the Display view's view model.

You need a way two communicate the changes from one view model to the other.

Comment: I understand the logic now and why it's not updating. But How can I achieve what I want. Is there some sample code that I can look at?

Comment: @Phil have a look at mvvmlight. Easier to create a single ViewModel feeding the 2 views with data in this instance